# extaract MSB and LSB from Hexadesimal address in C

Tags: c, hex

I have a pointer that holds a hexadecimal address
for example 0x0CBC
now I want a variable to hold the MSB address in hex format like 0x0c and another variable to hold he LSB address in hex format like 0xBC
How do I?

----EDIT

```
void *AddressFSubd=(void *)fSub;
```

AddressFSubd holds 0x0CBC

Comment: Did you try anything like shifting or and-ing with certain quantities ?

Comment: What type is your pointer and what does it point to ?

Comment: no!I want a method in C

Comment: my pointer is a function pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mask and shift to extract bytes:

```
unsigned int lsb = (unsigned int)ptr & 0xFF;
unsigned int msb = ((unsigned int)ptr >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

This is assuming that an `unsigned int` is at least as big as a pointer, otherwise the cast is undefined.

I'm not sure what you mean by "in hex format" - they're just bytes in memory, they don't have a format.